Where did Docker create bind mount on Windows host?
I've just created container with H2 database and bind mount "/h2-data", but i can't locate it on my Windows host. Where can i find this directory?
Actually, I want to bind folder in my working directory but I was mistaken a bit, so this directory was created. So i can't find it.
I put screenshot to this question and when i'm trying to click on /h2-data linked text nothing happened.
Link to the screenshot of Docker Desktop

It's probably within a HyperV machine. Use a directory mount rather than a docker volume if you want to see the files

@OneCricketeer, you're probably right, but i can't check hyper-v machine file system just because can't connect to it using Hyper-V manager. When I'm trying to connect to it i see only black screen. But anyway thanks for your answer!

Click on the icon (source). If it is on windows that directory will pop-out in file explorer.

It might have created a volume. Run docker volume ls to see if there's one called /h2-data.

@HansKilian, no, it's exactly mount, not a volume, i see /h2-data in mount section in container info.

You don't seem to have included the Compose file in the question; can you [edit] the question to include this?  The host directory should be the first half of the bind mount declaration, the part before the : in the volumes: line.
